# Find line of intersection between the planes.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I want to finde the line of intersection between the planes:

$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    3x-z+1 & = & 0 \\
    2x+y+z & = & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

I multiply row 1 by 2 and row 2 by 3 and get the equivalent system:

$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    6x-2z+2 & = & 0 \\
    6x+3y+3z & = & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Subtracting row 1 from row 2 I get

$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    6x-2z+2 & = & 0 \\
    3y+5z-2 & = & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Now the major problem: which of $x,y,z$ is best suitable to swap for a $t\in\mathbb{R}?$ Setting $t=z$ I get $y=\frac{2-5t}{3}$ and $x=\frac{2+3t}{2}.$ Setting $t=y$ I still get annoying fractions. But setting $t=x$ I get $z=1+3t, y=-1-5t$. Which is the answer according to the book.

1. How can one decide which variable to set $t$ as in order for the final answer to be in it's simplest form?
2. To get the answer the book has, I could have just set $x=t$ immediately , without having to do the elimination and would have gotten the same answer. Is this just a coincidence since in the first equation $y=0$, thus it would only work in similar cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving a system of equations from an elimination perspective it is good to get coefficients of $\pm1$ in the first column, so rewrite the system as
$$
\left\{
  \begin{array}{lcr}
    -z{\quad}+3x & = & -1 \\
    z+y+2x & = & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\right.
$$
Then add eq.(1) to eq.(2)
$$
\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    -z{\quad}+3x & = & -1 \\
    y+5x & = & -1 \\
  \end{array}
\right.
$$
Now it's more clear that letting $x=t$ will not generate fractions, and you obtain the required solution stated in your book $(x=t, y=-1-5t, z=1+3t)$.

Answer (score 0):

adding both equations we obtain:
$$5x+y+1=0$$ solving for $x$: $$x=-\frac{1}{5}y-\frac{1}{5}$$ thus $$z=-1-3\left(-\frac{y}{5}-\frac{1}{5}\right)=\frac{3}{5}y-\frac{2}{5}$$ and our line is given by
$$[x;y;z]=\left[\frac{-1}{5};0;-\frac{2}{5}\right]+t\left[-\frac{1}{5};1;\frac{3}{5}\right]$$ where $t=y$